# I created a step threading group of 10 users, but post running the plan its not showing the user count and not stop at 10 users

Tags: jmeter

[Here I have added 10 users in a step threading group and executed the test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnXlH.png)

[But post running the plan, the Jmeter is not displaying the user count and keep on running the test plan even after the 10 Users as well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb6Cb.png)

Please help me to resolve this scenario...

Answer (score 0):

JMeter displays the number of active virtual users in upper right corner of JMeter GUI

[image]

Also you can observe the chart of currently active virtual users using [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)) or by looking at the relevant chart of the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

---

If you expected to see 10 results it's quite hard to get it with the Stepping Thread Group because your current setup assumes running test for more than a minute and 10 virtual users will execute HTTP Request samplers **as fast as they can**, the real number of results/responses will mostly depend on your application response time but in majority of cases you will get much more than 10 responses.